# There is a link to 'view all articles' in all sites, which leads to a page not found if it is not Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, profile-page, 404-not-found, article

If you go to someone's Profile who made more than 10 posts, a link is shown to go to all questions, answers *and articles*:

[image: "View all questions, answers and articles" below "Top posts" on user profile page.]

The [*articles* link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=articles) adds `?tab=articles` at the end of the URL, which shows a 404 page (Page Not Found), unless you are on Stack Overflow.

I expect the message below *Top posts* to be "See all questions and answers" if the site doesn't have the Collectives/Articles feature.

Comment: @Luuklag thank you. My [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=view+all+articles+%5Bbug%5D) didn't show it.

Comment: SE search, do we need to say more...